# Setting object value with method in main class?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to set specific values of objects in an Array with a method.

```
public class BankAccount
{
private String name;

//constructor
public BankAccount(String firstName, String LastName)
{

name = firstName + " " + lastName;

}

public String getName()
{
return name;
}
```

Above is my `BankAccount` class, and I have another class named `BankAccountList`:

```
public class BankAccountList {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    BankAccount bankAccount[] = new BankAccount[2];

    bankAccount[1] = giveName("MR", "Travis");
    }

    public static void giveName (String firstName, lastName){

    }
}
```

How do I set the object name in `BankAccount[1]` to "Mr Travis" with the following `giveName()` method? I don't know what to put in `giveName` with the given parameter. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are basically trying to assign a new bank account object with the given name. So you could either pass the bank account object through the method or you could return a new bank account from the giveName method. If you passed it through you would not need to create a new object as you would just be passing in bankAccount[1] which is of type BankAccount.

Comment: My first tip is this: apply proper formatting, it'll make your code better readable. Second, you have created a `BankAccount` array, but note that the array does not yet contain any `BankAccount` objects.

Comment: Your code is unreadable and strange. It's basic java knowledge. Not for forum discussion...

Comment: Honestly, I've enjoyed this question. It is definitely a bit strange structure, but not unreadable. It might not be helpful to many others later, but it resulted in a lot of good discussion on how to best refine the code, and understanding how hard learning to code can be, before you adopt a few standards.

Answer (score 4):

Your `giveName` method should return the type `BankAccount`:

```
public static BankAccount giveName (String firstName, String lastName){
   return new BankAccount(firstName, lastName);
}
```

**Edit**:

Simply declaring `new BankAccount[]` does not populate any entries in the array (which you might expect based on experiences with other languages). The array will initially be empty, and there are multiple ways to populate it:

Inside a loop you could:

- Call the `BankAccount` constructor directly
- Delegate to another method that returns a new `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` (as the example above does)

This choice, like most programming decisions, is mostly personal preference. For a simple DTO with 2 string fields, delegating to another method might be overkill.

For a more complex DTO that requires validation, delegating to another method helps encapsulate that validation logic in a single place that is easily testable.

Comment: The `lastName` parameter needs a type.

Comment: Indeed :) Copied OP's code and add the return type. Fixed now.

Comment: I think the OP might think that creating an array will contain objects. However, it is worth saying that a newly created array only contains empty slots for the defined type of object, so no objects exist in the array. However, this method will actually create the object, return it, and give it to the array. 

Just so you know what happens! The giveName method is not really necessary here though, as you could skip it completely, and rather say | `bankAccount[1] = new BankAccount("MR", "Travis");` directly inside the main method

Comment: @KjetilNordin Yes, simply calling the constructor is probably sufficient here. In addition to trying to follow OP's original code, I like delegating the creation of the object to another method because that method can encapsulate any validation of the object before creating it. Obviously not needed for this trivial example, but it's just a style I've adopted over the years. I'll add a bit on the empty array initialization, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things worth mentioning here.

First of all, it seems like you do not have a complete understanding of the difference between static and dynamic. It is understandable, as I even now would have a hard time explaining it easily, even though I understand how it works. Your `BankAccountList` class has a main method, started from a static standard main method. your `bankAccount` array is defined within this main method, meaning it does not exist in the whole class, only inside the running main method.

Then you want to give name to a bank account in the list. Here you have created another static method, which knows nothing about what is inside your main method, and it does not contain any object which the parameters can be given to. In other words the empty function you have now, can't set any parameters to a bank account, because no bank account exists within the method.

I would recommend making the `giveName` method dynamic (which means just removing the static keyword), and move the method to the `BankAccount` class. Then you will efficiently have both a get and set method for name, which are dynamic, meaning it is valid per object instance of the class. After that, it is possible to first refer to an object in the array, and directly call the `giveName()` method on that particular object, which will set the name:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    private String name;

//constructor
public BankAccount(String firstName, String LastName)
{

    name = firstName + " " + lastName;

}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void giveName (String firstName, String lastName){
    name = firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

and:

```
public class BankAccountList {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        BankAccount bankAccount[] = new BankAccount[2];

        bankAccount[1].giveName("MR", "Travis");
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I noticed now another thing. The line where you create the array:
    BankAccount bankAccount[] = new BankAccount[2];

This does not create a populated array, it creates an empty array. in other words, you have not created a list with bank accounts, you have created a list which can hold bank accounts. You will have to create a bank account first, before being able to give it a name.

```
BankAccount bankAccount[] = new BankAccount[2];
bankAccount[1] = new BankAccount("MR", "Travis");
```

Now, your constructor already has parameters for giving an account a name, when created. So now you don't really need the giveName method. Unless you want to change it later:

```
bankAccount[1].giveName("MRS", "Davis");
```

Comment: I see a lot of other answers offer a lot of valid solutions and tips, but expect OP to automatically intuitively understand why their approach works, and how. This I think is the simplest way of solving the problem, without editing the code more than it has to be edited. That being said, I would also for instance change the name of giveName to setName to follow standards.

Comment: Well, this makes a lot of sense. I interpreted the `giveName` method as a helper method or something like that in the _BankAccountList_ class (assuming there was a `setName` in `BankAccount` because there was a `getName` and `setX` is the convention ) but this might be what the OP really wanted. Onle S/he can tell ;)

Comment: I also made a huge mistake first time around... forgetting to actually populate the array spaces... should be fixed now. I don't work much in arrays, more lists...

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use `giveName` method, you could just do it like this:

```
bankAccount[1] = new BankAccount("MR", "Travis");
```

But, if you really need to do it using a `giveName` method, you could do it like this:

```
// change signature to return `BankAccount` object
public static BankAccount giveName (String firstName, String lastName){
    return new BankAccount(firstName, lastName);
}
```

and call it like this: `bankAccount[1] = giveName("MR", "Travis");`

---

If you need `giveName` to have `void` as return type, then you need to pass the array in order to add the `BankAccount` inside the method and the position were it will be added. Like this:

```
// change in order to signature receive an array of `BankAccount`s and the position where it will be added
public static void giveName (String firstName, String lastName, BankAccount[] bankAccounts, int position) {
   bankAccounts[position] = new BankAccount(firstName, lastName);
}
```

and then call it like this: `giveName("MR", "Travis", bankAccount, 1);`

---

*Additional notes*:

- Remember array positions start at index `0`, not `1`, so you might want to consider adding bank account from `0`, not `1`, like this:
- This is the case if `giveName` is in the `BankAccountList` class. Otherwise, go for [KjetilNordin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894500/setting-object-value-with-method-in-main-class/52894898#52894898).

`bankAccount[0] = giveName("MR", "Travis");`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, it's not possible to have void as return type for things that involve changing of object value?

Comment: @mrtammy You can have `void` as return type if you only need to change something inside the method and don't need to return anything at all. But in this case you needed to assign to `bankAccount[1]` an object of type `BankAccount` so you need to return `BankAccount` as return type, not void. If you need `giveName` to have `void` as return type, read my answer updated.

Comment: @mrtammy this is the case if `giveName` is in the `BankAccountList` class. Otherwise, go for _KjetilNordin_'s asnwer

Answer (score 1):

You defined an array that will hold **BankAccount** objects, so to add elements into it with the function ***giveName()*** you need to modify that function as following :

```
public class BankAccountList {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    BankAccount bankAccount[] = new BankAccount[2];

    bankAccount[1] = giveName("MR", "Travis");
    }

    public static BankAccount giveName (String p_firstName,String p_lastName){
      return new BankAccount(p_firstName, p_lastName)
    }
}
```

Comment: YouneS The `p_lastName` parameter needs a type

Answer (score 1):

You need `set` methods!

Add this to class BankAccount:

```
public void setName(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.name = firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

so you should call setName instead of giveName. Like this:

```
 bankAccount[1].setName(String firstName, String lastName)
```

Another thing, I suggest you use the set method in the constructor of your object:

```
//constructor
public BankAccount(String firstName, String LastName)
{

   setName(String firstName, String lastName);

}
```

Comment: `bankAccount[1].setName(String firstName, String lastName)`? with two parameters?

Comment: It only has one attribute 'name'

Comment: I copied this `bankAccount[1].setName(String firstName, String lastName)` from your answer... it has two parameters.

Comment: concatenation of the two

Comment: You also need to correct this line: `setName(String firstName, lastName);` inside the constructor. It is incorrect